# Neural network model has way more features than samples but yields good test accuracy

Tags: neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

I am recently doing a bioinformatic machine learning project. We have over 470,000 features and only 700 training samples and 300 test samples. We used a perceptron with 1 hidden layer to train. However, the result is surprisingly well, even though the number of features are way more than that of data. Intuitively, we used PCA, lasso regularization and elastic net regularization for dimension reduction. The prediction accuracy for 40 selected PCA is higher, but the addition of lasso or elastic net penalty even reduces performance slightly, although the feature space is over 470,000.

The whole thing is really counter-intuitive. It should be the case that when you have so much features, the model will not yield a consistent unique solution and the model is doomed to overfit. However, the test set results is surprisingly well.The prediction accuracy for age ranged from 10 to 100 is less than 4. We try to print the weight vector but it doesn't give us much information. It seems that the neural network reduces many of those weights very close to zero. Lasso reduces even more weights close or equal to 0, yet the result is worse.

Are there possible explanations to explain this? Or are there some approaches we can use to see what is going on?

Comment: As a first step, before digging into the model, do a 5-10 fold CV to measure the test performance, and see if they are still good. Test set may be biased.

Comment: Can you think of any reason the test set is biased? We did some CVs using other datasets. The results were not as good, but still ok.

Comment: For example, some samples in your test set might be very similar with others in the training dataset. If so, when you overfit, you wouldn't even notice.

Comment: Thanks. We did some CVs. What would be the criteria to say that the model is biased? We have several that are close to the original performance and 1 with noticeable worse performance.